# mailto: links gobbled in a route

Tags: backbone.js, mailto

I'm using the jquery linkify plugin on a relatively simple Backbone view. Links to web pages outside this app work properly and using browser view source, I see the mailto links are properly generated. But clicking a mailto link appends /mailto:q@example.com to the current URL (e.g., http://example-acme.staging.myservername.com/mailto:q@example.com).

If I copy the generated HTML using Inspector and paste it into the source of arbitrary pages (not in this app), the mailto links function as expected, opening a new message window from my mail client. Problem is the same in Chrome and Firefox.

Have you seen and fixed this issue?

Comment: This line is in the view class's render().then() callback:  <br/>
<br/>
`$(el).find('#thankYouMessage').html(destMsg).linkify();`  <br/>
  <br/>
The generated HTML is:  <br/>
  <br/>
`<div id="thankYouMessage">Thank you. Please view <a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a> or <a href="http://www.example.com">www.example.com</a> for more details. Email <a href="mailto:qwer@example.com">mailto:qwer@example.com</a> or <a href="mailto:qwer@example.com">qwer@example.com</a> for info.</div>`

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?  Or a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sorry, having trouble formatting the comment. But no, would be really hard to get a fiddle, this is a small part of a complicated Backbone setup.

Comment: The generated HTML is fine, and this is confirmed with you copying and pasting it.  I think there is another problem with this page, but without being able to see the page, I can't give any specific advice.

Comment: Do you mean the rest of the generated page or some part of the Backbone code?

Comment: Backbone, or some other JavaScript.  If the DOM really appears the way you have there, then there should be no issue, so I'm wondering if there is a weird click handler or something.

Comment: Nothing should be grabbing the click, this is outside of any selectors in the events hash:

Comment: `        events: {
            'click #ptUltimateQuestion .btn': 'toggleBtn',
            'click #idSubmit': 'idSubmit',
            'click #reviewSubmit': 'reviewSubmit',
            'click #offerImageUrl': 'offerClick',
            'click #offerDescription a': 'offerClick',
            'change #screenName': 'formatScreenName',
            'keypress #id input': 'idSubmit',
            'keypress #reviewForm input': 'reviewSubmit'
        },
`

Answer (score 0):

Just for closure: I added an event handler in the handler use window.location.assign(mailto) and that gets the job done. Not necessarily 'correct' but practical. @Brad, thanks for chiming in!